# How to stop (deallocate) an Azure virtual machine with Dasein-cloud API

Tags: web-services, azure, virtual-machine

I'm using Dasein-cloud API and I want to stop a virtual machine.

Actually I can stop the VM using `stop(id)` method from `VirtualMachineSupport` class but the VM state is STOPPED and I'm still being charged.

I want to stop the VM and deallocate it (STOPPED DEALLOCATED status)

Do you know if a method exist and where can I find it ?

Comment: Nobody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

I use the Azure API REST services, parse the obtained XML to get the datas I need and execute some requests using`SSLSocketFactory` and `HttpsURLConnection`.

Hope it helps someone else waiting a real API !